# check for any item in string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    if (args[0].ToUpper().Equals("DOWNLOADPOS"))
    {
        DownloadPOS();
    }
```

will run DownloadPOS(), if the first item in args is downloadpos, I would like to check against all the items in args??
please advise?

I was previously using:

```
//if (args.Contains(pos))
//{
//    DownloadPOS();
//}
```

but then wasnt sure how to sure the upper on it

thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? (Comes to midnd: looping thru array; LINQ functions). That's pretty basic stuff mate, for someone using MVC. See the identical answers below pour.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (arg.Any(x => x.Equals("DOWNLOADPOS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
    DownloadPos();
}
```

If you need to support special cultures (e.g. Turkish), use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` instead of `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Comment: +1 for using `string.Equals` overload, For more info [The Turkish İ Problem and Why You Should Care](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (args.Any(x => x.ToUpper().Equals("DOWNLOADPOS")))
{
    DownloadPOS();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq, [Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method

```
var exist = args.Any(x => x.ToUpper().Equals("DOWNLOADPOS"));
if (exist)
{
    DownloadPOS();
}
```